# How to get catalogsearch/result page content on a cms page

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I have `Magento version 1.9.2.1`. When I search for some `query_string` then url becomes `http://domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=query_string`.

But I want to get same result on different url and url will be `http://domain.com/custom/query_string`
OR `http://domain.com/query_string`.

Is it possible to get search result with different url?

Answer (score 0):

In the Form that submits that search has method as GET you can make it POST and create a custom module to process that request with your desired frontname

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using rewriteRule.

To get url from `http://domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=query_string` to `http://domain.com/custom/query_string` rewriteRule will be like :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^custom/([^/]+)/?$ /catalogsearch/result/?q=$1 [QSA,P,NC]
```